# Why does time() malfunction after midnight in my MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that my Query affects. The tables are called **flightSched** & **Alteration**.  In both tables the **arrivalTime** column is of type TIME.

The query runs just fine until the **$CurrentTimePlus4Hours** variable elapses midnight. When this happens, the query doesn't yield any records, although the table has data ranging from all times of the day and night. Find below my code.

```
$currentDay = date('l');
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = date('H:i:s', strtotime('-30 minutes'));
$CurrentTimePlus4Hours = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+240 minutes'));

$query2  = "SELECT * FROM flightSched WHERE don = '$currentDay' 
                 AND depOrArriv='Arrival' 
                 AND arrivalTime BETWEEN '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' AND '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours'
                 ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC ;";

$query2 .= "SELECT * FROM Alteration WHERE don = '$currentDay' 
                 AND depOrArriv='Arrival'
                 AND arrivalTime BETWEEN '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' AND '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours'
                 ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC ;";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query2)) {

        do
        {
                if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo "<tr " . $variable . "><td>"; 
        echo '<img src="php/displayImage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' "align="middle" width="110" height="35" >' . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  "
             . $row['flightNo'] ;
        $flightNo = $row['flightNo'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['airline'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['origin'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['arrivalTime'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['status'];
        echo "</td></tr>"; 

        if ($variable == 'id=basicBoard')
        {
        $variable = 'class=alt';
        //echo $variable;
        } 
    elseif ($variable == 'class=alt')
        {
        $variable = 'id=basicBoard';
        //echo $variable;
        } 
                  }
                  $result->free();
               }
               /* print divider */
               if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            //    printf("-----------------</br>");
               }

        }
        while (@$mysqli->next_result());
echo "</table> <br/> <br/>";

}
```

I have tried to figure out why this happens but failed to fix the issue. Can someone kindly point out where I am going wrong in the code?

Comment: Can you please give some output and, if possible, some debug-code? Also consider removing all unrelated code from your example, so to make it easier for others to understand what is going on.

Comment: Because the time belongs to the NEXT day, yet your query is requiring `WHERE don = '$currentDay' ` ?

Comment: Print out `date('Y-M-d H:i:s', strtotime('+240 minutes'));` for a hint, then look at your full WHERE criteria

Comment: @Joe How do I solve this? Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try this `$query2  = "SELECT * FROM flightSched WHERE don >= '$currentDay'` instead?

Comment: @Izkata I followed your advice and I still think my WHERE criteria makes alot of sense. In my opinion it should read show me all the records in the tables between 30 minutes ago (e.g. 2013-OCT-28 11:30) and 4 hours from now (e.g. 2013-OCT-29 04:00). Am I missing anything?

Comment: @jerdiggity Thanks, I tried your solution, and sadly it doesn't yield any records at all.

Comment: @jerdiggity It [looks like](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) `$currentDay` is the string `"Monday"`, so I'm not sure what to expect with that

Comment: @SirBT Looks like Joe and I had the same thought.  You're querying for things where `don = "Monday"` _AND_ where most of the time span is on `Tuesday` - those are very unlikely to overlap, unless there's more information about your data you haven't explained to us.

Comment: The obvious questions at this point are: What is your schema? Can you create a table with sample data to see what you have in there? Can you create a table to see what result you're expecting to get out of the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to compensate for the time lapse by offsetting what the "current" day is:

```
$midnight = strtotime('today');
$now = time();
$tomorrow = $midnight + 86400;
$diff = $tomorrow - $now;
$offset = $now;
// Number of seconds in 240 minutes = 14400
if ($diff <= 14400) {
  $offset += $diff;
}
$currentDay = date('l', $offset);
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = date('H:i:s', strtotime('-30 minutes'));
$CurrentTimePlus4Hours = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+240 minutes'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried your suggestion and it didn't make a difference. When the current time is 21:57 it stops yielding any records.

Comment: Do you think that maybe I am using the incorrect TYPE in the table structure, Do you think changing the arrivalTime column (which is currently of type TIME), to DATETIME would make a difference?